# powershell -exclude did not exclude all the files from list

Tags: powershell

I have this script:

```
$list= @("inetpub", "Program Files", "Program Files (x86)", "ProgramData", "Windows", "Users"); Get-Item "C:\*" -exclude $list | Remove-Item -Recurse -force
```

and it should delete everything that is root but nothing from the list and what is inside the folders from the list. When I run it, somehow the script deletes some of Program Files folders like notepad++. How can i fix it?

The script is deployed using GPO like this
`-ExecutePolicy Bypass -command "$list= @("inetpub", "Program Files", "Program Files (x86)", "ProgramData", "Windows", "Users"); Get-Item "C:\*" -exclude $list | Remove-Item -Recurse -force`"

Edit: If it's deployed as a script not as a command it is working. But i would still like to know how can i make it work as a command

Comment: It works for me.  What version of powershell is it?  You don't need @() to make an array.

Comment: i am using powershell 4.0.  I Think is worth mentioning that i am deploying the script. If used locally i does the job but if its deployed it does more than it should

Comment: How is it deployed?

Comment: Using GPO, not as a script but as command

Comment: Maybe you should update the question with the full command.

Comment: sorry, i updated the question now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that a startup script?  This works from cmd at least:

```
powershell $list = 'inetpub','Program Files','Program Files (x86)','ProgramData','Windows','Users'; Get-Item C:\* -exclude $list ^| Remove-Item -Recurse -force -whatif
```